# Select count vs select statement performance when the query will return 0 rows

Tags: mysql, database-performance, query-performance

I'm looking through some code an old developer wrote, who is no longer around. I found something that I'm not quite sure makes sense to be doing, but I don't think I have enough knowledge or good enough google fu to find the answer, so here goes:

The code looks like this:

```
var queryCount = SELECT COUNT(Col1) FROM MyTable WHERE ColumnInIndex = 'SomeValue'

if(queryCount == 0)
   return [];

var results = SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3,... FROM MyTable WHERE ColumnInIndex = 'SomeValue'
return results;
```

So my first thought was that seems redundant and should just use the results from the select query in the first place. I dug a little farther because the commit suggests its for perf tuning.

From what I understand from googling is that count in fact would be faster because it doesn't have to return any data or pull any rows & can rely solely on the index.

However, in the pseudocode I've written above, the case in which the where clause wouldn't return any rows it seems like we wouldn't get a performance boost because neither count nor select would return any results. Plus, when there are actually results we're doing two of these queries instead of just the one.

Additionally, it seems like since we're using the rows in the first place, we should just get the data in one query vs making two trips to the db.

Am I completely off base here?

We're using MySql v5.6.46

Comment: while query writing you use * it is ok. But in production environment never used SELECT *. always used required columns names. Because it will also affect on your performance. Apart from that What I understood from your 1st query is if you are using COUNT() then if their is no record found it will give you 0. but if you are using SELECT column_1 then it will give you null. So, according to you if condition. I feel that use SELECT column_1. Which will return blank Null

Comment: @PTank thanks for your answer, I've removed * from the queries, since the code actually doesn't have it, it was just poorly written example code. I'm not too worried about the null vs array check since this is all wrapped up with an ORM that handles the type checking appropriately, I've just replaced the ORM calls with the sql that they translate to. My question here is more about the performance impact of having the extra count query before hand & whether having it will improve the performance or degrade it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  [But read all the way to the end!]

Two steps is inefficient -- in any version of MySQL.  If there are zero rows, the Optimizer will do essentially the same amount of work for either `SELECT`.

If there are some rows, then the first `SELECT` is a waste of time.  See the programming acronym 'KISS'.

The pseudo-code implies that the 'return' is an empty array; I am assuming that is the case for either query when there is no matching row?

A side note:  I hope `ColumnInIndex` means "a column that is *first* in some index".  If the column is not first, neither query will use the index.  (This comment does not affect the main Question.)

Another side note (aimed at PTank):  When there are no matching rows, neither of these

```
SELECT col FROM ... WHERE ...
SELECT  *  FROM ... WHERE ...
```

return any rows; they do not return `NULL` for column(s).  (The use of `*` is 'bad' for multiple reasons unrelated to the original Question.)

Oh, yet another comment. `COUNT(col)` checks `col` for being not-NULL before counting the row.  `COUNT(*)` simply counts the rows.  In almost all cases, you should use `COUNT(*)`; it's simpler, faster, and probably gives the same answer.  (The answer will be the same if `col` is the `PRIMARY KEY`.)

Good grief!!  That means that your first query is *not* redundant!  The odd-ball case is when `col1` is `NULL` in *every* row.  The first query will return a count of zero, but the second query will return some rows (with the first column `NULL`).

Was this a trick question?

Comment: I should've left it as SELECT COUNT(*) as that's how it is translated by the ORM. The queries are definitely using an index - we'd know if they weren't :D - I think part of the confusion is my attempt at abstracting out the code for this format. To confirm, the return for an empty select in the second sql statement would be an empty array as well. Thank you for confirming my suspicions, I just wanted a sanity check because I wasn't finding an answer about what the optimizer would do with 0 rows between the two queries (I'm sure with the right search the answer is out there)

Comment: @Corey - Simplification/abstraction is handy, but it can backfire!

Comment: @Corey - I can't address the "empty" select vs array  -- which client language?  what API, etc.  (Again the abstractification is in the way.)  All the APIs I know of would equate them.  PS, `EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )` is another variation on this theme.  It has advantages, but not in this example.

Comment: PPS -- 1 command, even if complex, maybe faster than 2 commands -- because of the overhead of _any_ command.  (Receiving, unmarshalling, parsing, optimizing, mashalling, sending.)